# how to show when last time RHEL system was "patched"?

Tags: rhel, yum, patch

At work we are tasked with (i.e during and inspection or audit) showing *when the system was last patched*.  This is all that is asked.

Of course I asked the inspector how do you want me to show you this... what do you want me to type, and the response is... *not my job, i don't know, you are supposed to know*.

So should I write a c code that simply displays a date less than 5 days ago whenever run and some other official looking jargon?

I kinda only know `uname -a` and say go reference this kernel version with the list of releases and dates published by redhat, and doing an `rpm -qa` and say here go reference all 2000+ rpm versions to what is most current.

**Is there some `yum` command that is the proper way to answer the question: *when was the last time you patched your system?***

This is on RHEL 7.9 x86_64

Comment: Maybe last time yum updated something on the system? For Debian based systems the modification time of /var/log/dpkg.log if the file is a non-zero size would do it.

Comment: Create a package list with update / install dates, with the latest install at line 1 : `$ rpm -qa --last > list.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum history` will give you a record of all the package operations performed using `yum`, including upgrades. You can use that to determine when the system was last “patched”, or better yet, fully upgraded.